# ActionController::ParameterMissing (param not found: order)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I am trying to send a post request using the Postman chrome extension to my Ruby on Rails app, but i keep getting the error

> ```
> ActionController::ParameterMissing (param not found: order):
> app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:27:in order_params'
> app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:20:in create
> ```

The code in my orders_controller is

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery :except => :create

  def new
    @order = Order.new
  end

  def index
    @orders = Order.all  
  end

  def show
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])    
  end

  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    render text: params[:product]   
  end

  private

  def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(:product)
  end
end
```

My key Value pairs to the Postman extension are `product[product_name]` `Samsung`

Comment: Can you add the rails-log of the request. Would want to see the incoming parameters

Answer (score 8):

For you to use `params.require(:order)`. the incoming parameters should be something like `{"order"=>...}`

Check the documentation at http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html to use Strong Parameters,.

Based on your information about the key-value pairs used, there is no key called "order" in the incoming-data. That's the reason - its failing.

Hope, this helps

Comment: It did work, I changed the Key value pair to order[product_name]. Thanks. If i may ask do you have any insight on how i would save the incoming post requests?

Comment: You got to use ActiveRecord#save http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/save .
Please upvote and mark the answer as BEST/CORRECT if it works. That will help peers looking at this question

Answer (score 2):

Probably the params method is requiring something that you don't have. Inspect the params.

This worked for me:

Controller:

```
def progress_params
    params.require(:progress).permit(:game_id, :level_id)
end
```

---

View:

```
<%= link_to "Completed", progresses_path(:progress =>{:game_id => @level.game_id.to_i, :level_id => @level.id.to_i} ), :method => :post %>
```